# Tomcat logback.xml

Tags: java, logback, tomcat9

When I run my application in Tomcat 9 on Windows it picks up the logback.xml file in the shared lib folder just fine. However, when I run the same configuration on Ubuntu, it doesn't seem to pick up the logback.xml file (this is my assumption since I don't see any logs generated). Permissions look fine on the file and the common.loader is set to load ${catalina.base}/lib, amongst other values. The configured log folder is set to 777. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**Edit**

In catalina.out I see

> Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Which means that slf4j cannot find an implementation. However, I definitely have logback-classic-1.2.3.jar and logback-core-1.2.3.jar on my classpath (siblings to the slf4j-api jar file). I don't understand why it is saying that there is no binding when logback is present on the classpath.

Looks like the issue isn't finding the logback.xml file but rather finding the binding to slf4j.

Comment: do you use maven for your project dependencies ? if yes, can you edit your post and provide the pom.xml file ?

Comment: I really have no idea why this didn't work. I started on a fresh instance and everything worked fine. I eventually blew away the old instance that wasn't working.